# How to check for valid file name format in kdb/q?

Tags: kdb

I'd like to check that the file names in my directory are all formatted properly. First I create a variable `dir` and then use the keyword `key` to see what files are listed...

```
q)dir:`:/myDirectory/data/files
q)dirkey:key dir
q)dirkey
`FILEA_XYZ_20190501_b233nyc9_OrderPurchase_000123.json
`FILEB_ABC_20190430_b556nyc1_OrderSale_000456.meta
```

I select and parse the `.json` file name...

```
q)dirjsn:dirkey where dirkey like "*.json"
q)sepname:raze{"_" vs string x}'[dirjsn]
"FILEA"
"XYZ"
"20190501"
"b233nyc9"
"OrderPurchase"
"000123.json"
```

Next I'd like to confirm that each character in `sepname[0]` and `sepname[1]` are letters, that characters in `sepname[2]` are numerical/temporal, and that `sepname[3]` contains alphanumeric values.

What is the best way to optimize the following sequential `if statements` for performance and how can I check for alphanumeric values, like in the case of `sepname[3]`, not just one or the other?

```
q)if[not sepname[0] like "*[A-Z]";:show "Incorrect Submitter"];
  if[not sepname[1] like "*[A-Z]";:show "Incorrect Reporter"];
  if[not sepname[2] like "*[0-9]";:show "Incorrect Date"];
  if[not sepname[3] like " ??? ";:show "Incorrect Kind"];
  show "Correct File Format"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`like` will not work in this case as we need to check each character. One way to do that is to use `in` and `inter`:

```
  q) a: ("FILEA"; "XYZ"; "20190501"; "b233nyc9")
```

Create a character set

```
  q) c: .Q.a, .Q.A
```

For first 3 cases, check if each charcter belongs to specific set:

```
  q) r1: all@'(3#a) in' (c;c;.Q.n)  / output 111b
```

For alphanumeric case, check if it contains both number and character and no other symbol.

```
  q)r2: (sum[b]=count a[3]) & all b:sum@'a[3] in/: (c;.Q.n) / output 1b
```

Print output/errors:

```
q) errors: ("Incorrect Submitter";"Incorrect Reporter";"Incorrect Date";"Incorrect Kind")
q) show $[0=count r:where not r1,r2;"All good";errors r]
q) "All good"
```

Comment: Thaks, Rahul. How would you perform a similar function to r1 on a singleton list as opposed to a general list, e.g., a:"OrderPurchase"

Comment: Solution to above comment:
a:"OrderPurchase"
all@(a) in c / returns 1b
all@(a) in .Q.n / returns 0b

Comment: That's right. You can also remove '@'.  `all a in c` will do the job.

Comment: This works great for a single list of strings. What if I had multiple lists of strings I wanted to check simultaneously? e.g. `(("FILEA"; "XYZ"; "20190501"; "b233nyc9"); ("FILEB"; "ABC"; "20190524"; "c963lax8"); ("FILEC"; "LMN"; "20190523"; "x465pxd3"))`

Comment: You could do it using adverbs. But the simple way is to just convert `r1` and `r2` into functions and iterate over `a`. Good point about this approach is this code for r1 and r2 will remain same as it is for normal list.   `q) r1: {all@'(3#x) in' (c;c;.Q.n)} each a` `q)  r2:{(sum[b]=count x[3]) & all b:sum@'x[3] in/: (c;.Q.n) } each a`   And finally error printing code will be:  `q) {show $[0=count r:where not x;"All good";errors r]} each r1,'r2`

Answer (score 2):

If your valid filenames alway have that same structure (specifically 5 chars, 3 chars, 8 chars, 8 chars) then you can use a single regex `like` statement like so:

```
dirjsn:("FILEA_XYZ_20190501_b233nyc9_OrderPurchase_000123.json";"F2ILEA_XYZ_20190501_b233nyc9_OrderPurchase_000123.json";"FILEA_XYZ2_20190501_b233nyc9_OrderPurchase_000123.json";"FILEA_XYZ_2A190501_b233nyc9_OrderPurchase_000123.json";"FILEA_XYZ_20190501_b233%yc9_OrderPurchase_000123.json";"FILEA_XYZ_20190501_b233nyc9_OrderPurchase_000123.json");


q)dirjsn
FILEA_XYZ_20190501_b233nyc9_OrderPurchase_000123.json
F2ILEA_XYZ_20190501_b233nyc9_OrderPurchase_000123.json
FILEA_XYZ2_20190501_b233nyc9_OrderPurchase_000123.json
FILEA_XYZ_2A190501_b233nyc9_OrderPurchase_000123.json
FILEA_XYZ_20190501_b233%yc9_OrderPurchase_000123.json
FILEA_XYZ_20190501_b233nyc9_OrderPurchase_000123.json

q)AZ:"[A-Z]";n:"[0-9]";Azn:"[A-Za-z0-9]";
q)dirjsn where dirjsn like raze(AZ;"_";AZ;"_";n;"_";Azn;"*")where 5 1 3 1 8 1 8 1
"FILEA_XYZ_20190501_b233nyc9_OrderPurchase_000123.json"
"FILEA_XYZ_20190501_b233nyc9_OrderPurchase_000123.json"
```